# WebDriverIO : getText(), click() methods are not working - it says they are not function

Tags: webdriver-io

HomePage:

> class homePage {
>
> ```
> get pageHeader() { return $('//h1[contains(text(),"Best")]'); }
> get pagesubHeader() { return $('div.banner-text-content>p.sub-text'); }
> get supportLink() { return $('//li/span[contains(text(),"Support")]') }
> ```

HomeElement Page:

> const homePage = require("../Pages/homePage")
>
> describe("Home Page Elements handle", function () {
> it("Verify HomePage Elements",  async function () {
> // await browser.url('https://www.freshworks.com/');
> let text =homePage.pageHeader.getText();
> console.log(text);
>
> ```
> })
> ```
>
> })

Error:

1. Home Page Elements handle Verify HomePage Elements
   homePage.pageHeader.getText is not a function

}

module.exports = new homePage();

Answer (score 1):

You use async, so this tells me you are working with WebdriverIO Async mode. This means, all the functions will mostly return a promise.
So proper way of doing it is that you need to await for the browser/element functions:

```
const pageHeader = await homePage.pageHeader;
const text = await pageHeader.getText();
console.log(text);
```

Remember, $, $$ and basically any functions of the browser or of the element are promises in async mode, so essentially, you attempted to "getText()" or "click()" on a promise object.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but still I am facing the same issue. how can I check if my webdriverIO is running in Async mode. I am complete brand new to webdriverIO and JS

Comment: now I am getting an error like Cannot read property 'isDevTools' of undefined

Comment: That looks like it's related to some addon installed along with the webdriverio. Do you have this [plugin](https://webdriver.io/docs/devtools-service/) installed?